# Get memory address from LabVIEW array

Tags: c, memory-address, labview

I wrote a C++ DLL with Visual Studio and add a C wrapper to use it on several langages (C++, Python, LabVIEW, ...). In this one, I am dealing with images, so 2D array. I created a labview library using LabVIEW tools so I attached this library to my project.

First, the function to allocate and free the handle for the DLL is working correctly so the communication seems okay.
Moreover, my DLL function take as parameter a pointer on the first pixel of the image, so on the first value of the tab, in order to recreate a matrix (library OpenCV) to perform some operations.

But I don't know how to get the memory address of the array on LabVIEW and the different posts on internet are not always clear.

Here is the C function:

```
__declspec(dllimport) unsigned short* __stdcall imAdjustBrightness(void* handle, void * ptrImg, int width, int height, int inputType, int brightnessValue)
{
    if (handle)
    {
        EpsImageProcessing* data = (EpsImageProcessing*)handle;
        return data->imAdjustBrightness(ptrImg, width, height, inputType, brightnessValue);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And the screenshots for the VI :

[image: main VI]
[image: library function]

Thank you in advance for any advice/help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass in a pointer to a labview array you can configure the "call library function" node like this:

1. On the Parameters tab select the parameter that you are interested
   in
2. in the right side panel select "Adapt to type" in the "Type"
   drop-down
3. select "Array Data Pointer" in the "Data Format" drop-down

this setup should pass in a pointer to the first element of your array.

the call library function node's options are documented [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvexcodeconcepts/configuring_the_clf_node/)

Comment: Is it working even with 2D array (image) or do I have to convert it into 1D array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MoveBlock` LabVIEW function.

Here is [link](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Developer-Center-Resources/Dereferencing-Pointers-from-C-C-DLLs-in-LabVIEW/ta-p/3522795) from NI forum.